# Converting from C to Racket Scheme

Tags: c, recursion, scheme, racket, code-translation

I have written the following C code to recursively solve for a given problem, which is to take in a non-empty list of integers and a target value, and return the closest positive value without going over the target. e.g. (3 4) with target 2 should return 1.  The only combination is -3 + 4 = 1.:

```
int closest(int arr[], int target, int i, int n)
{
    
    if (i == n)
        return 0; 

    int sum1 = arr[i] + closest(arr, target - arr[i], i + 1, n); 
                                                                
    int sum2 = -1 * arr[i] + closest(arr, target + arr[i], i + 1, n); 

    if (abs(sum1 - target) < abs(sum2 - target))
    {
        return sum1; 
    }
    else
    {
        return sum2;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the problem is meant to be written in Racket, with the restriction of using car + cdr and not using let to create a variable for sum1/sum2 and I'm having major difficulties.

So far:

```
(define closest (lambda (l target i n)
  (cond
    ((= i n)0) 
   )
  )
  )
```

My question is: how does one convert the arr[i] and pointer to car/cdr logic? I vaguely understand that it controls two values but iterating seems to be breaking my brain in two.

Comment: Did you read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) then [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) ? Don't convert C to Scheme, but do **think in Scheme** ! Also provide some [mre]...

Comment: As it stands I can't work out what the C version is meant to do: without a problem description which is not just code, there's just no easy way to know if any Racket solution is correct.  (And also, as the other commenter said: don't start in C and convert to Racket: think in Lisp.)

Comment: Presumably the C function is initially called with `i` as 0... and it goes up by one each time it's called again, until it's equal to n... that's straightforwardly translated to a linked list and car/cdr.

Comment: The interesting part is not being able to use let and temporary variables. Are you allowed to create helper functions, or just the one?

Comment: Start with this skeleton: `(define (closest lst target) (if (null? lst) 0 (the rest of the code here)))`.

Comment: Note that you can translate `(let ((x v)) e)` into `((lambda (x) e) v)`, and it generalizes to multiple definitions in the "obvious" way. The iteration is easier to get a grip on if you first rewrite your C function to use pointer arithmetic (remove `i`) and imagine that there is a way of determining from the pointer that you've reached the end of the array.

Comment: "without going over the target" your C code does _not_ do that. you use  `abs` to compare.

Comment: `(define closest (lambda (arr targ) (if (null? lst) 0 ((lambda (sum1 sum2) .... ) (+ (closest (cdr arr) (- targ (car arr))) (car arr)) (- .... ) ))))`. this mirrors the C code, so, find the closest value either below or above target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should learn how to "think in Scheme", but "thinking in Scheme, in C" can also be valuable.

First, use pointer arithmetic instead of array indexing.
If you squint hard enough, you will see that `*p` is a bit like `(car p)` - "the first element" - and `p + 1` a bit like `(cdr p)` - "the rest of the elements".
Then you count down to zero instead of up to n (that is, you ask "how many elements are there left to do?" instead of "how many elements have we done?").

```
int closest(int *arr, int target, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0; 
    /* I rearranged these two slightly in order to emphasize the symmetry. */
    int sum1 = closest(arr + 1, target - *arr, n-1) + *arr; 
    int sum2 = closest(arr + 1, target + *arr, n-1) - *arr; 
    if (abs(sum1 - target) < abs(sum2 - target))
    {
        return sum1; 
    }
    else
    {
        return sum2;
    }
}
```

Now we need to get rid of the "`let`-bindings", `sum1` and `sum2`.
We can do that by introducing a function:

```
int pick(int target, int sum1, int sum2)
{
    return abs(sum1 - target) < abs(sum2 - target) ? sum1 : sum2;
}

int closest(int *arr, int target, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0; 
    return pick(target,
                closest(arr + 1, target - *arr, n-1) + *arr,
                closest(arr + 1, target + *arr, n-1) - *arr);
}
```

(As [the Fundamental Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering) says, any problem can be solved by adding a level of indirection.)

This can be formulated in Scheme in a pretty straightforward way - it's mostly a matter of changing the punctuation.
Note that we don't need the counter any more since we can tell from the list itself that we have reached the end:

```
(define (pick target sum1 sum2)
    (if (< (abs (- sum1 target)) (abs (- sum2 target)))
        sum1
        sum2))

(define (closest arr target)
    (if (null? arr)
        0
        (pick target
              (+ (closest (cdr arr) (- target (car arr))) (car arr))
              (- (closest (cdr arr) (+ target (car arr))) (car arr)))))
```

And now we can "inline" `pick`, removing the `target` parameter since it's available in the surrounding context:

```
(define (closest arr target)
    (if (null? arr)
        0
        ((lambda (sum1 sum2)
             (if (< (abs (- sum1 target)) (abs (- sum2 target))) sum1 sum2))
         (+ (closest (cdr arr) (- target (car arr))) (car arr))
         (- (closest (cdr arr) (+ target (car arr))) (car arr)))))
```

Comment: from sufficiently far away, everything is a change in punctuation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a translation of what you are doing. I think the main thing that is tripping you up is how `cons` `car` works. "Vectors" (or lists) in racket actually look like this:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 empty)))
```

which translates into this in C

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

So how do we get the `i`th element from it?! Well if you look at your recursion, we don't actually *need* to. We are, effectively, always getting the next element from the list after the one we just processed. We step through the list one at a time and don't care about what we have already calculated.

Effectively, translated to C, what we are doing in racket is doing pointer arithmetic to get the next element and passing that pointer back into the function as our new `arr`. The rest of the list is "forgotten" only in the sense we can't access it. Our calculations we have done up to this point are still remembered.

I believe you are using `i` and `n` to track where we are in the array so we could remove them since we don't need to actually track which element we are on:

```
#lang racket
(require test-engine/racket-tests)

(define (closest arr target)
  (define sum1 (if (or (null? arr)) 0 (+ (car arr) (closest (cdr arr) (- target (car arr))))))
  (define sum2 (if (or (null? arr)) 0 (+ (* -1 (car arr)) (closest (cdr arr) (+ target (car arr))))))
  (if (< (abs (- sum1 target)) (abs (- sum2 target)))
      sum1
      sum2))

(check-expect (closest '(3 4) 2) 1)
(test)
```

Comment: "_'Arrays"'in Racket actually look like this..._" -- careful... that statement may cause more confusion than clarity. Some Lisps have actual array types, e.g. Common Lisp, and Racket also has [`math/array`](https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/7.5/doc/math/array.html). `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons nil)))` is a linked list, and `[1, 2, 3]` in C is an actual array, i.e., elements are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory; not quite the same thing.

Comment: Scheme calls arrays vectors.